# How to use app.config file with a C++/CLI to configure assembly binding in VS 2012?

Tags: .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I am currently using the Microsoft BCL Async library ([here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx?PageIndex=3&CommentPosted=true&wa=wsignin1.0)) across a project with a large number of interdependent assemblies all compiled against .NET 4 Full Profile, I have had to use assembly binding redirect in each project to get it to compile (as per issue 2 [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx)).

The problem I now have is that I consume one of these libraries from a C++/CLR DLL project, it does not actually need to use async but I have the following compilation error:

2>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "ImInterface.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "ImInterface.dll" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

I have added the same app.config file that I have used in all of the C# projects but it does not seem to be having any effect in the C++ project. Do I have to place it in a specific directory or perform any other steps to enable the app.config file to be recognised?

The content of my app.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.11.0" newVersion="2.5.11.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.11.0" newVersion="2.5.11.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Regards,
Anthony

Comment: did you mange to fix this Anthony? I'm having a similar error though mine is not to do with c++

Comment: Hi James, unfortunately not - no one has offered any useful advise. I have been away over Christmas so I'll be looking in to this again next week as it is an important project for us to use.
What specifically is your problem with? A C# project? The app.config file in my post should help with that...

Comment: Mine's to do with C# and Portable Class Libraries for Windows Phone/8 I found a stackoverflow question that was similar to mine shortly after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597797/using-async-ctp-with-portable-class-library. Although the error is quite similar it doesn't seem relevant to your problem unfortunately

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and as it turned out, **`<SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>`** helped.

**Before you continue reading, note that the problem seems to *only* happen when the C++/CLI project is built using the "Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)" platform toolset!** That is if you don't need to create a DLL which is compatible with WinXP, switch to "Visual Studio 2012 (v110)" instead and you should be fine.

**Let me elaborate my scenario:**

I have a C++/CLI console application project **(ConsoleAppCLI)** targeted for WinXP (v110_xp).  ConsoleAppCLI references a library **(AsyncLib)** which has Microsoft.Bcl.Async installed via NuGet:

```
[ConsoleAppCLI.vcxproj]   (C++/CLI, .NET 4.0 v110_xp)
          |
          |
   [AsyncLib.csproj]      (C#, .NET 4.0)
          |
          |
 [Microsoft.Bcl.Async]    (via NuGet)
```

**I had the exact same problem and the app.config didn't help either, but what did help was the following:**

1. Unload ConsoleAppCli.vcxproj
2. Edit the vcxproj File directly
3. Find the reference to the library which has the Async nuget package installed (in my case, a `<ProjectReference>` to AsyncLib.csproj)
4. **Between `<ProjectReference>` and `</ProjectReference>`, ADD THE FOLLOWING: `<SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>`**

Note however, that ConsoleAppCLI was my top-level project in the dependency tree. If you have Assemblies which depend upon the C++/CLI assembly which produced MSB3268, you likewise have to add `<SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>` to the reference (e.g. if i had an additional C# library which has ConsoleAppCli as dependency, i would have to make the reference to ConsoleAppCli `<SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>` as well).

This solution is coming from [over here](http://sanderstechnology.com/2011/warning-msb3268-you-are-about-to-experience-pain/10646/#.UXAcTMqcFDc), by the way.

Comment: +1 I had the same problem with a .Net 4.0 project using the async extension, which meant that our main C++ project would no longer build. Added the "SpecificVersion" and all is good again... Thanks

Comment: I can also confirm, this describes the real problem and the solution is working fine. Thank you!